# Supabase not saving user session, just returns null

Tags: javascript, supabase

I am using site, react, and Supabase to create an application.

Currently, I am using Supabase auth to register a user with an email and password.

It creates the user successfully. Also, I have disabled email verification.

The problem is that the session returns null everywhere except the `handleSubmit()` function, directly after I register the user.

Everywhere else, the `getSession()` just returns null.

Here is my code:

```js
  async function getSignedInUser() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.getSession();
    console.log(data);
  }

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
      email,
      password,
    });
  }

  getSignedInUser();
```

And if I called `getSignedInUser()` inside `handleSubmit()`, it would log the session to the console, but it is null everywhere else.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Would you be able to share your code that you use to initialize Supabase as well in your question?